# How do I replace specific number to word?

Tags: python, replace

If there is an input:

`"My phone number is 123780936407, and there are two 0 in it."`

I wish the output to be:

`"My phone number is 123780936407, and there are two zero in it."`

However, if I use the replace, the output will be:

`"My phone number is 12378zero9364zero7, and there are two zero in it."`

How can I do to get the desirable output? Much thanks!

Comment: You need to check if there is no numbers around the number you are looking for

Comment: Can you add just two more sample example, please?

Comment: `print("My phone number is 123780936407, and there are two 0 in it".replace(" 0 ", " zero "))` ?

Comment: For another example:                                    input=” There are 10 students in class, two got 0.”                                                                 
output= “ There are 10 students in class, two got zero. “

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use [rindex](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rindex.htm) which give last index of your specific string.

```
str1='My phone number is 123780936407, and there are two 0 in it.'
i=str1.rindex('0')
```

strings are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) in Python, just create a new string which includes the value at the desired index.

```
addStr=' zero '
str1 = str1[:i] + newstring + str1[i + 1:]
print (str1)
```